# how to put the first name of each cell as a row name and order a data in a table frame?

Tags: r

I have a CSV which looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5c717eb36e2d3dae5cad)

My expected output should look like this:

```
             channel_count        characteristics_ch1  . . . . . 
GSM1098572       gps                       1
GSM1098573       SRA                       1
GSM1098574       SRA                       1
```

Comment: Could you pls specify the parameters of your csv file such that `read.csv` or `read.table` can read it? I mean, if you went that far...

Answer (score 0):

rownames(data) =  data$varname

Comment: rownames(data) =  data$varname #name of column
rownames(x) <- value
rownames(x) <- data[ ,1] # select first column

Comment: Désolé  Dominic, I did not look at the data; used the comments because I cant edit from my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems your "csv" file is still far from being a "regular csv". If you're not an experienced used, you might find it worthwhile to explore other data cleaning softwares, such as [OpenRefine](http://openrefine.org/).

To give you an example of what can be achieved in R, I took the first "row" of your data and fiddled with it a little bit. (Here, "txt" is a string containting your first row/chunk of data):

```
txtsub <- gsub("\\.", "\t", txt) # Turn dots into field separators
txtsub <- gsub(";", "\r\n", txtsub) # Turn semicolons into linebreaks
dat <- read.delim2(text=txtsub,header = FALSE) # read transformed text into a dataframe.

head(dat)

#          V1                  V2
# 1 GSM1098572       channel_count
# 2 GSM1098572 characteristics_ch1
# 3 GSM1098572     contact_address
# 4 GSM1098572        contact_city
# 5 GSM1098572     contact_country
# 6 GSM1098572  contact_department
```

There's still miles to go before you get to your expected results, but I don't think anyone here will do all this work for you. But if this can help you get started, all the better. And if getting your data in good shape is something pressing, maybe hiring someone to do it for you is something to consider. Just thinking out loud here.

In any case, good luck and feel free to contact me for follow-up questions.